# How to develop minor (1.x) AND major (2.x) features of managed package in a single DE org

Tags: managed-package, isv, beta-managed-package, release

I have a managed package were I constantly add smaller features (to big for patches) by increasing the minor release version: 1.12, 1.13, 1.14.

Now I also want to work on some disruptive changes (for Releases 2.x), that I only want to build, test and improve with a small focus group.

As we use a Single DE org = Packaging Org approach we cannot simply use another DE org for this. What options do we have?

I came up with those alternatives:

1. Add a Sandbox to the DE / packaging org and work on the 2.0 changes there.

   - GOOD: Clear seperation of code
   - BAD: No chance to create a release
2. Use an extension package for the development of all the disruptive 2.0 changes

   - GOOD: Clear seperation AND Could be released and Upgraded
3. Keep 2.0. and 1.X code in a single org and be sure to never put 2.0 metadata into a 1.X release.

   - GOOD: No merging and extra org overhead
   - BAD: High risk that 2.0 code mistakenly makes it into a 1.x release.

Besides that fact that doing Single Org Development is not optimal, which ideas or approaches would you recommend here?

Comment: Have you considered using a Patch org? http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_patches_about.htm

Comment: @AndrewFawcett: Sure I considered patch orgs. But they are not sufficient. Neigther for maintaining the smaller features increments in the 1.12, 1.13,.. stream. Nor for the 2.0 changes. As you know you cannot really add or remove anything in a Patch org.

Comment: You don't mention a version control system - do you use one? If you do, and have kept the package namespace out of the code, then branching in there and pushing the 1.x "head" into your normal namespace org (e.g. "myns") and pushing the 2.x "branch" into a separate namespace org (e.g. "myns2") could work. This would be a two DE org plus version control solution not the "single DE org" solution in your question.

Comment: I use Git but I want to work with a single org.

Comment: OK. A "BAD" about option 2 is that all the classes you have in the core packages are not available in your extension package (with the exception of global ones but making classes global limits future refactoring). And where you need to change the core for the benefit of the extension you have to re-package and re-deploy which is slow. So unless the new features are very independent of the old it can become painful quickly.

Comment: +1 for @KeithC's comments, if Salesforce default vision of developing in packaging / patch orgs is something you have outgrown, and asking such questions as above is such a sign, moving completely out into managing version in source control is the only way. In this case, the use of packaging and patch orgs purely become kind of "warehouses" where you bring to together something you want to release from source control to package it and get it out the door.

Answer (score 1):

I think it fair to say the question is now moot and that such development would be done using `sfdx` (or the new `sf` CLI) and scratch orgs.

Use of a single, long-lived org for managed package development, regardless of 1GP or 2GP, is simply bad practice, open to mistakes that could seriously mess up your package.

Sure, 1GP still requires the "packaging org" but use of scratch orgs during development is much cleaner, more robust and safer, only pushing the package metadata to the packaging org when ready to create a beta or release version and thus minimising scope for human error or inappropriate changes.